# Unable to predict sentiment of emoticons

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, utf-8, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to predict the sentiment of facebook's comment using vader sentiment analysis tool[1] but it is not able to predict the sentiment of emoticons ,it is working in some comments while in some other it is not.

```
result=db.post.find() 
analyzer=SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
for sentence in sentences:
    vs=analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)
    print("{:-<65} {}".format(sentence,str(vs)))
```

The excerpt of the output is-

```
I am rishav ---------------------------------------------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.615, 'pos': 0.385, 'compound': 0.3612}
Woohooo✌️------------------------------------------------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
```

It is running on some sentences but not on other,I am traversing from the database.Also, in some cases when I use only 1 emoticon it works but on using multiple times, it doesn't works.

How to resolve this error?

[1]:[Vader Sentiment Analysis tool](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment)!

Comment: What is `client.facebookData`? Where did you pull the data from? What's the output of `type(db)`? What's the output of `type(result)`?

Comment: Its a mongoDB data(JSON document),db type is `<class 'pymongo.database.Database'>` and result `<class 'pymongo.cursor.Cursor'>`

Comment: facebookData is the name of database in my machine and I pulled it using facebook API

Comment: Sentiment analysis is not expected to work on individual utterances with any precision. The technique is useful *in spite of* its obvious accuracy problems when you analyze a large enough collection of utterances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems alright but not your example. 
If you go through the VADER code, first it fetches the score of each word from its dictionary. For that, the sentence is sliced using spaces.
In the example you provided, there are no spaces between the emoticons, not even the words. So VADER considers it as a single word.

You can verify this using your code

```
analyzer=SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

sentences = ["Woohooo✌️", "Woohooo  ✌️"]

for sentence in sentences:
    vs=analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)
    print("{:-<65} {}".format(sentence,str(vs)))
```

Output is:

```
Woohooo✌️------------------------------------------------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
Woohooo  ✌️----------------------------------------------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.446, 'pos': 0.554, 'compound': 0.7351}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Update: this is no longer the case: `Woohooo✌️------------------------------------------------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.667, 'pos': 0.333, 'compound': 0.4588}`  
`Woohooo  ✌️----------------------------------------------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.667, 'pos': 0.333, 'compound': 0.4588}`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try the "emot" library:

https://github.com/NeelShah18/emot

```
text = ':-) Woohooo✌️'

def clean_mean(val):
    return val.replace('_', ' ').replace('-', ' ').replace(':', ' ')

for emoti in emot.emo_unicode.EMOTICONS:
    if emoti in text:
        text = text.replace(emoti, clean_mean(emot.emo_unicode.EMOTICONS.get(emoti, '')))
        print(emoti)
        
for emoti in emot.emo_unicode.UNICODE_EMO:
    if emoti in text:
        text = text.replace(emoti, clean_mean(emot.emo_unicode.UNICODE_EMO.get(emoti, '')))
        print(emoti)
        
for emoti in emot.emo_unicode.EMOTICONS_EMO:
    if emoti in text:
        text = text.replace(emoti, clean_mean(emot.emo_unicode.EMOTICONS_EMO.get(emoti, '')))
        print(emoti)
        
print(text)  


analyser.polarity_scores(text)
```

Ouput:

```
{'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.294, 'pos': 0.706, 'compound': 0.9501}
```